# Buscar cualquier tipo de datos entre dos parámetros en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Quiero buscar en la string `linea` cualquier tipo de string o de caracteres. Un ejemplo de 3 strings:

```
OPLApache SSL
OPLGoogle.es SSL
OPLT3ra SSL
OPLCss SA SSL
```

Lo he probado de estas maneras:

```
datos = re.search(r"OPL([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+)SSL", linea)
datos= re.search(r"OPL(.*)SSL",linea)
```

En primer ejemplo no hay problema pero en la resta de ejemplos me aparece el siguiente error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Hay algún método para buscar con `re.search` en las strings y obtener lo siguiente?

```
Apache
Google.es
T3ra
Css SA
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes algún otro error en tu código; por eso hay que publicar un ejemplo completo, mínimo, verificable como este:

```
import re

patrones = [
r"OPL([a-zA-Z0-9_\. ]+)SSL",
r"OPL(.*)SSL"
]

tests = [
"OPLApache SSL",
"OPLGoogle.es SSL",
"OPLT3ra SSL",
"OPLCss SA SSL"
]

for patron in patrones:
    print("Probando patrón", patron)
    for test in tests:
        datos = re.search(patron, test)
        if datos:
            print(f"Resultados: ", test, datos.groups())
        else:
            print(test, "No encontrado")
```

Este código tiene dos listas: una de expresiones regulares y otra de líneas de pruebas. El código itera para probar cada línea contra cada expresión regular.

El resultado es:

```
Probando patrón OPL([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+)SSL
Resultados:  OPLApache SSL ('Apache ',)
Resultados:  OPLGoogle.es SSL ('Google.es ',)
Resultados:  OPLT3ra SSL ('T3ra ',)
Resultados:  OPLCss SA SSL ('Css SA ',)

Probando patrón OPL(.*)SSL
Resultados:  OPLApache SSL ('Apache ',)
Resultados:  OPLGoogle.es SSL ('Google.es ',)
Resultados:  OPLT3ra SSL ('T3ra ',)
Resultados:  OPLCss SA SSL ('Css SA ',)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Edición**

Agregue `\.` al patrón para reconocer la línea `OPLGoogle.es SSL`.

Comment: No existe la forma de realizar dicha consulta con solo un patrón de búsqueda? Sin usar los patrones de dentro de la lista `patrones`?

Comment: Modifique el primer patrón para producir el resultado deseado. Revisa mi respuesta.